# Printing all BST nodes when recursively searching through tree in Java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am trying to iterate through a BST in java to return node data when it matches a parameter. However, the problem that I am having is when the recursive functions find the node, it correctly returns the required node data but it also returns all of the other node data of the path to get to the desired node.

I have tried adjusting the recursive return statements and creating variables to store the end result in and then return that variable but both either don't function or still have the excessive return results.

A couple of notes about this file, current is the node, and there are a bunch of basic BST functions but they are named slighly different. `getData()` pulls the data from the node, `getLeftChild()` gets the left child, `getRightChild()` gets the right child, and `toString()` just returns the data in a fancy way.

```
private static String nodeLookup(String s, Node current) {

        String returnMeaningStatement;


        int compareInt = s.compareTo(current.getData().toLowerCase());

        if (compareInt == 0){
            return current.toString();
        }

        else if (compareInt <=-1){
            if (current.getLeftChild() == null){
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            else {
                return nodeLookup(s, current.getLeftChild());
            }

        }

        else{
            if (current.getRightChild() == null){
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            else {
                return nodeLookup(s, current.getRightChild());
            }
        }
```

If the path to the node desired is, Node 1, Node 2, Node 3 and the data in those nodes is :
Node 1: Hello
Node 2: My Name
Node 3: Is

The desired returned results should be

> Is

The actual results are

> Hello My Name Is

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/333247/why-does-recursion-return-the-first-call-in-the-stack-and-not-the-last

Comment: You have to think about the stack frame. What is actually being returned? Your code is the second version of the example I posted. You just have to rethink how you are returning the values. And return according to the first version of the post in the link.

Comment: Provide more code.. it is not enough

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the line `return current.toString();`

I don't know what `current.toString()` returns, but I guess it returns the path.

try to replace it with `return current.getData()`